# Using Panoply command line scripts

Tags: netcdf, command-line, panoply

I have been using Panoply for a while now, and I noticed that you can export a command line script to reproduce the figure. If I look at the first lines of the script, it tells me that I should run it as:

```
java -jar PanoplyCL.jar script.panjs
```

However, in the `jars` directory I cannot find PanoplyCL.jar:

```
lopezom@kw12964:~/bin/PanoplyJ/jars$ ls
commons-lang3-3.4.jar  monte-cc.jar          slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar
itext-2.0.0.jar        netcdfAll-4.6.3a.jar  slf4j-jdk14-1.7.12.jar
jhlabs-filters.jar     Panoply.jar
```

I tried passing the .panjs script as an argument to Panoply.jar but it skipped it because it was expecting a netCDF file:

```
000002 WARNING: Panoply parseCommandLineOptions - Skipping 'script.panjs'. No netCDF filename extension
```

Did PanoplyCL.jar used to be included in earlier versions? How can I run CL scripts? I really want these figures to be reproducible without using the GUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted the author, Dr. Robert B. Schmunk, and it appears that the command line version of Panoply is under a beta release only. However, as specified in the website, you must contact him to become a beta tester.

I tested PanoplyCL.jar and it worked only after I upgraded from Java 7 to Java 8.